# How to get month and day from the timestamp in java

Tags: java, android

How to get `month` and `day` from the timestamp in Java

**FORMAT:** `2019-01-21T05:56:46.000Z`

- 21
- JAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String ts = "2019-01-21T05:56:46.000Z";
String date = ts.split("T")[0];
String[] splitDate = date.split("-");
int day = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[2]);
String month = "";
switch(Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]))
{
    case 1:
        month = "JAN";
        break;
    case 2:
        month = "FEB";
        break;
    .
    .
    .
}
System.out.println("Day: " + day + ", Month: " + month);
```

Comment: its a school boy solution

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

```
public static Date string2Date(String dateStr){
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));// GMT +0. It depends on your purpose
            return sdf.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[Date and Time Patterns document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)